# How to display song currenttime and duration by using AVAudioPlayerNode

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayernode

I'm making an audio player using AVAudioPlayerNode and playing a song with some effect (delay, pitch change, rate change etc) works, but I'm stuck on displaying song current time and duration.
AVAudioPlayerNode seems not have like AVAudioPlayer.currentTime or .duration.

I'd really appreciate if you can help me to display currenttime and duration by using AVAudioPlayerNode.

Answer (score 14):

For the current time, this is what I use:

```
- (NSTimeInterval)currentTimeInSeconds
{
    AVAudioTime *nodeTime = self.playerNode.lastRenderTime;
    AVAudioTime *playerTime = [self.playerNode playerTimeForNodeTime:nodeTime];

    NSTimeInterval seconds = (double)playerTime.sampleTime / playerTime.sampleRate; 
    return seconds;
}
```

In addition to the render time in an abstract time base, the player node offers conversion of this time into its own playback timeline via `playerTimeForNodeTime`. Also respects pausing etc.

Comment: @KeitaBickOhshiro if it works for you, you can mark the answer as correct or upvote it to make it visible for other members.

Comment: This gives the actual Position but if you do AudioNode.ScheduleSegment(...) the Position will not be resetted to 0, it just continues to count.

Comment: How do solve this, @DanielDirtyNativeMartin. please reply

Answer (score 8):

Here it is in swift:

```
private func currentTime() -> NSTimeInterval {
    if let nodeTime: AVAudioTime = myAvAudioPlayer.lastRenderTime, playerTime: AVAudioTime = myAvAudioPlayer.playerTimeForNodeTime(nodeTime) {
       return Double(Double(playerTime.sampleTime) / playerTime.sampleRate)
    }
    return 0
}
```

Just replace **myAvAudioPlayer** with your AVAudioPlayerNode!

Happy coding!

Comment: This only appears to work if the node is playing. If stopped it returns zero.

Answer (score 7):

***Swift 5:***

**duration time**, using `AVAudioPlayrtNode`'s `AVAudioFile`

```
extension AVAudioFile{

    var duration: TimeInterval{
        let sampleRateSong = Double(processingFormat.sampleRate)
        let lengthSongSeconds = Double(length) / sampleRateSong
        return lengthSongSeconds
    }

}
```

according to [WWDC 2014:  whats new in core audio , mins 54](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCBHpdpUGy8)

---

Then currentTime:

```
extension AVAudioPlayerNode{

    var current: TimeInterval{
        if let nodeTime = lastRenderTime,let playerTime = playerTime(forNodeTime: nodeTime) {
            return Double(playerTime.sampleTime) / playerTime.sampleRate
        }
        return 0
    }
}
```

Thanks @Brian Becker

Answer (score 5):

For the duration of the `AVAudioPlayerNode` **SWIFT 4:**

```
func durationOfNodePlayer(_ fileUrl: URL) -> TimeInterval {
    do {

        let file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: fileUrl)
        let audioNodeFileLength = AVAudioFrameCount(file.length)
        return Double(Double(audioNodeFileLength) / 44100) //Divide by the AVSampleRateKey in the recorder settings

       } catch {

          return 0
       }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

For the duration, *.length* property of *AVAudioFile* worked.
I divided the number of sample frames in the file by the sample rates(44100hz).

For the currenttime, tentatively I use *UISlider.value* and synthesize the value with the sample frames.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should give you that ability...

```
extension AVAudioPlayerNode {
    var currentTime: TimeInterval {
    get {
        if let nodeTime: AVAudioTime = self.lastRenderTime, let playerTime: AVAudioTime = self.playerTime(forNodeTime: nodeTime) {
            return Double(playerTime.sampleTime) / playerTime.sampleRate
        }
        return 0
    }
}
```